# Is there a better way to write this recursive function that throws "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this function that takes a number and "translates" it to word, but when I try to add some logic to make it work even when the number is negative (min. -99999), I get an error message in the console that says:

"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Is there a better and easier way to write this function so that I don't exceed the call stack size?

```
const num = [
    "zero",
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
    "ten",
    "eleven",
    "twelve",
    "thirteen",
    "fourteen",
    "fifteen",
    "sixteen",
    "seventeen",
    "eighteen",
    "nineteen",
];
const tens = [
    "ten",
    "twenty",
    "thirty",
    "forty",
    "fifty",
    "sixty",
    "seventy",
    "eighty",
    "ninety",
];

function number2words(n) {
    let digit;

    if (n >= 0) {
        digit = n % 10;
    } else {
        digit = 10 - (n % 10);
    }

    if (n >= 0 && n < 20) {
        return `${num[n]}`;
    }

    if (n >= 20 && n < 100) {
        return `${tens[Math.floor(n / 10) - 1]} ${digit != 0 ? num[digit] : ""}`;
    }

    if (n >= 100 && n < 1000) {
        return `${num[Math.floor(n / 100)]} hundred ${
            n % 100 == 0 ? "" : number2words(n % 100)
        }`;
    }

    if (n >= 1000 && n < 10000) {
        return `${num[Math.floor(n / 1000)]} thousand ${
            n % 1000 != 0 ? number2words(n % 1000) : ""
        }`;
    }

    if (n >= 10000 && n < 20000) {
        return `${num[Math.floor(n / 1000)]} thousand ${
            n % 1000 != 0 ? number2words(n % 1000) : ""
        }`;
    }

    if (n >= 20000 && n < 100000) {
        return `${tens[Math.floor(n / 10000) - 1]} ${
            num[Math.floor(n / 10000)]
        } thousand ${n % 1000 != 0 ? number2words(n % 1000) : ""}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it exceeds the stack size, that means you're not terminating properly and you run into infinite recursion. It shouldn't take THAT many recursive calls to finish this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What would you suggest to refactor this function to be better structured? And do you have any idea on how to make it work on negative numbers too?

Comment: I just tested your code (with numbers from 0 to 99999) and I did'nt face any Maximum call stack error. How can I reproduce ?

Comment: Making it work on negative numbers should be easy: ``if (n < 0) return `negative ${number2words(-n)}` ``.  But without seeing your work, I can't tell you why your current attempts are failing.

Comment: [I don't get an error when I use a negative number](https://jsbin.com/wixagapeqo/1/edit?js,console). I don't get any output either but at least no error. As for suggestion, I'd start by trying to find which input breaks it and trying to debug it to see why it it gets into infinite recursion.

Comment: If you want to handle negative number I would say just adding a condition at the begining of your function (if (n<0) return "minus" +  number2words(-n);)

Comment: I apologize if my query was not clear, but I meant that the function works UNTIL I try to add some logic to make it work if I pass a negative number.
But clearly as VLAZ said, the problem was that the logic I added was not terminating the function. Now it works perfectly with "(if (n<0) return "minus" + number2words(-n);)".  
Thanks to everybody!

Comment: You asked if there was a better way to code this.  I don't know if it's any better, but I created one that's very different: https://gist.github.com/CrossEye/b25754942846ca5f4c1e8bb8cdec8ae4

Comment: Thenk you @ScottSauyet! I don't know if you've ever worked with typescript, but do you think it would be difficult to refactor my code or your code to typescript code and then compile it down?

Comment: @Zakaria: Although I'm pretty sure that neither would be difficult, I stay as far away from Typescript as I can.